# @MainActor does not apply to catch part of docatch

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I am currently using a function with @MainActor to publish changes to my UI in my SwiftUI app. Unfortunately, the attribute only dispatches UI updates on the main queue in the do part of the docatch block. When I publish UI changes in the catch block (i.e. errorMessage), it says that "publishing changes from background threads is not allowed" even though I wrapped the whole function in the @MainActor attribute.

Is there a way to fix this? Shouldn't the @MainActor apply the UI changes in the catch statement too? Should I just use .receive(on:)) for the error message?

```
@MainActor
func signUp(creds: CredentialDetails) async {
    do {
        let authDataResult = try await Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: creds.email, password: creds.password)
    } catch {
        print("There was an issue when trying to sign in: \(error)")
        self.errorMessage = error.localizedDescription
    }
}
```

Comment: I think the problem is that although this method is marked MainActor, the `self.errorMessage` setter is not. But it's easy to get on the main actor in the catch block so why not just do that? Say `await MainActor.run {`

Comment: May be related to thing said in [this article](https://mobile.blog/2022/03/28/swift-why-is-my-mainactor-code-running-in-the-background/)

Comment: @PylypDukhov Nice link!